# OAuth 2.0: SAML Bearer Assertion Flow

Tags: wkwebview, aswebauthenticationsession

We have been trying to implement OAuth 2.0 SAML Bearer Assertion authentication in our enterprise iOS application. We are not receiving the SAML Assertion id response in WKWEBVIEW/Aswebauthenticationsession. Please  confirm whether OAuth 2.0 SAML Bearer Assertion possible in NATIVE iOS development. Please suggest how this can be achieved.

Our resource server is SAP ABAP ECC, Identity provider is Azure. After opening the web view the azure authentication happens but we are not receiving any SAML response in web properties.